# Adding OnClick property to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I'm trying to add arrays into onclick button for my simple JavaScript calculator.

My first try was that `process(text[i]);` in the code but it doesn't work at all.

So, I converted the array item to string and gave to the onclick function.
then it runs a strange way.

Would you let me know how I can pass to correct type?

```
var text = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "SQRT", "POW", "RNDM", "MAX", "MIN"];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var child = document.createElement('button');
  child.innerText = text[i];
  child.value = text[i];
  var temp = text[i].toString();   //<-- convert to make sure it is string

  child.onclick = function () {                
    process(temp);   //<-- it doesn't work properly, and it won't accept "process(text[i])???".
  }

  label1.appendChild(child);
}        

document.body.appendChild(label1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to step away from my computer, but below is almost working. `ops` is undefined once it gets into the onclick being set. Not sure why. Hopefully somebody else can build off of this.

```js
function process(operation) {
  alert(operation);
}

var ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "SQRT", "POW", "RNDM", "MAX", "MIN"];

for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
  var child = document.createElement('button');
  child.innerText = ops[i];
  child.value = ops[i];

  (child.onclick = function() {

    process(ops[i]);
  })(i)

  // label1.appendChild(child);
  document.body.appendChild(child);
}

// document.body.appendChild(label1);
```

Comment: I added the enclose of "function (i)" in your code as adeneo's suggestion. then it is also working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @tomtom, excellent. Can you click the check mark below the arrows on the left to indicate this answer was the solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

As already well explained by @adeneo, the problem is that all `onclick` handlers use the same `temp` variable. One more way of providing a separate scope for each iteration, is to use `forEach` method instead of `for` loop:

```
["+", "-", "*", "/", "SQRT", "POW", "RNDM", "MAX", "MIN"].forEach(function(text) {
    var child = document.createElement('button');
    child.innerText = text;
    child.value = text;
    child.onclick = function () {
        process(text);
    }
    label1.appendChild(child);
});
```

**Sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/kq1mpm3g/